# Extracting Wikipedia Articles: Redirects?

Tags: api, redirect, wikipedia

I'm working on something that shows the raw data on a wikipedia page. I've got it working really well, but I've run into an issue with redirects. Sometimes when the app goes to the page, it says, `"This is a redirect from a title that is <b>fully protected</b> from editing for any of several possible reasons. For more information follow the category link. <ul><li><b>Please do not replace these redirected links</b> with a link directly to the target page."`, and obviously I don't want that.

This is the link that I'm using. (Queen Elizabeth for example)
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extract&titles=Elizabeth_II_of_the_United_Kingdom&format=xml

I tried adding `&redirect=yes`, but the page says that its an unrecognized parameter. I couldn't find anything on the internet, is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's redirect**s**, also prop=extract**s**:
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Elizabeth_II_of_the_United_Kingdom&format=xml&redirects=1

Comment: The devil is in the details. Thanks.